# -e (if file exists) trickiness in perl finding sendmail

Tags: string, perl, sendmail, exists

Trying to test a list of common sendmail locations, i thought to just loop and -e test, but there is something I'm not understanding here, wrote a little subroutine to explain this better;

```
sub mail_z
{
my $sendmail = '/xampp/usr/lib/sendmail';  #tried with/without/ and included the .exe

if(-e $sendmail){print"found SendMail";}else{print"NOT Found SendMail";}

    open ( MAIL, "| $sendmail " );
        print MAIL "From: $sender\n";
        print MAIL "To: $recipient\n";
        print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
        print MAIL "$body\n";
        print MAIL "\n.\n";
    close ( MAIL );
}
```

The result of this sub is that it prints "NOT Found SendMail" to the page and then uses sendmail to email me.  Clearly it finds it just not with -e what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't know why `-e` is failing if the file exists, but the error case should probably return or otherwise do something more than just print a message instead of continuing on to try to use the program that it just didn't find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i wasn't understanding was that in xampp there is a hook to catch the abbreviated [/xampp/usr/lib/sendmail] when using [open MAIL]. Its probably there to simulate an online Apache server but it isn't deep enough to affect -e.  The *actual* path to sendmail on my xampp is [/xampp/usr/lib/sendmail.exe] and this works for both tests. Note; most installations of xampp, sendmail is in [xampp/sendmail/sendmail.exe]

Doing a readdir test on my local [/xampp/usr/lib/] Dir shows me the file [sendmail.exe] but when i run the same readdir test online host at [/usr/sbin/] i discover the file is called [sendmail] without extension and doing an -f and -d (file or folder) test on [sendmail] online it shows its a file.. So my original problem will be fine once uploaded, i just have to remember to add the exe for local tests.

Holli and Grinnz answer was a fine alternative route, however i needed to find out what was wrong with my code before proceeding.

Comment: I think you'll need to say much more about your platform and setup for us to know what's going on in your particular case. Even then, this might be more appropriate for ServerFault as it's more of a sysadmin thing than a programming thing.

Answer (score 2):

Behold the power of CPAN

```
use Unix::Whereis;

my $sendmail = whereis('ffmpeg');
```

FWIW, the module uses these tests

```
if ( -f $bin && -x _ && -s _ ) {
# ...
```

Comment: I would recommend [File::Which](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Which) instead.

Comment: These work when the file is in your PATH. That's not always the case. Even then, I suggest that you don't rely on a search of the PATH to find it if you don't very tightly control that (which is why taint checking insists on that). I write a lot more about this in [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org/).

Comment: Then what's the alternative? Looking everywhere?